# Memory Issue in iPad Application

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

In our application we are display list of images in UIScrollView. And all image are in HD. So when we are load that page 2-3 times then application will crash. Because of the memory issue.

Please give me suggestion what am i do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggestion of what to do: post some code so we might have a clue as to what you are doing and where any potential memory leak might be?

Comment: In the absence of code, the best I can suggest is, implement your UIViewController subclass's didReceiveMemoryWarning: method and ditch whatever resources you're holding that aren't in active use at the time.

Comment: No their is not a single potential leak. I have check with static analyzer. We are showing the list of the news with HD images.

Comment: What sizes are the images? Try it with non HD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what that page looks like, you could consider implementing them as a UITableView.  Why?  UITableView is excellent for only displaying what's currently on the screen.

It's a little more complicated to set up than simply adding a few UIImageView objects to a scrollView, but the whole thing might perform better, and manage the loading/unloading of the objects.

UITableView objects are quite configurable to the point that a user would never know they are scrolling through a table.  I think of them as a content queueing/dequeueing system.  It just takes a bit more to set up.  You would for example have to:

- create your own UITableViewCell class and override the prepareForReuse method, so to unload your images (i.e. set the imageView.image = nil)
- optionally consider an AsynchronousImageView that also has disk caching capability (if your content is not local to the device)
- override the DataSource/Delegate methods so that the height of each cell is calculated properly, given the dimensions of your UIImageView

Basically read the UITableView programming guide in depth, especially the part about UITableViewCells and providing content.

I'd write more but I don't know exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Static analyzer is nowhere near as good as running leak detection in instruments. And even it needs a couple of steps to ensure retain-cycled objects are found - @bbum has an awesome post on that [over here](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)